# How to make button group 100% with non-equal size buttons without btn-group-justified (one large and one small) in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make some button group in which one button occupy rest width and one button with some fixed width set by content. How to achieve this.

It can look like this for different resolutions:

```
| <- 100% ->                              |
| large button fill               | fixed |

| <- 100% ->                       |                   
| large button fill        | fixed |

| <- 100% ->                |
| large button fill | fixed |
```

I tested justified and but it give equal size button.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the button to `calc(100% - 20px)` for instance, if that fixed width is 20 px.

Comment: 20px is not know but it know that it contains fixed content.

Comment: Do you know what's the width of that content inside? If by saying it's fixed content you mean it's always the same then you may look into Chrome's Developer Tools and extract the width by inspecting said element and in looking into it's computed properties.

Comment: Fixed mean only that is has some width but nobody know how it will be rendered in Firefox 4000 or NewBrowser version One. I can not assume that is has some pixels width - it is not good way to design UI.

Comment: How about floating, then? Make the fixed content float to the right. Or use flexbox, it should be perfect for this task. If those do not satisfy you - use my solution posted here and add Javascript into it so you always use the width of that element, whatever the browser is.